# How to customize each column's fluidity in css?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Okay so I have three columns in css. [Click here for a screenshot of the columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM4ZY.png) When I adjust the window's size, the far left column's left side stays at a fixed place. I want this same thing with the right column's right side as well. All other sides (middle column, right side of left column, left side of right column) are adjustable. Right now, the only fixed place is the far left column's left side.
Is it even possible to have customized fixes (?) like this?
Also, how do I get the columns to stay fixed at the top, rather than the bottom? I also circled this in the picture. When one column is bigger than the others, the smaller ones will stay at the bottom height, not the top like I would like.
I would really appreciate the help. I am a bit new to css and html, so I am still learning. Also, I apologize if I didn't explain it very well, I hope the screenshot and the code helps! Thank you a lot!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Add a card effect for ticker(s) */

.card {
  background-color: rgb(24, 28, 41);
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(5, 105, 256);
  /*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 1%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: rgb(5, 105, 256)/*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style the topnav links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change color on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30.5%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(5, 105, 256);
  /*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .column {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 28, 41);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>


<div class="card">
        <label for="ticker">Ticker(s):</label>
        <input type="text" id="ticker" name="ticker" value="" style="text-transform:uppercase"><br>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>INPUT INFO LATER INPUT INFO LATER</p>
 </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>INPUT INFO LATER</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>INPUT INFO LATER</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` in the `row` class.

NOTE: if you remove the `box-sizing: border-box` style on everything (`*`), you will also get rid of the unequal spaces in the sides.

```css
/* Add a card effect for ticker(s) */

.card {
  background-color: rgb(24, 28, 41);
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(5, 105, 256);
  /*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 1%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: rgb(5, 105, 256)/*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style the topnav links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change color on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30.5%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(5, 105, 256);
  /*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row {
  display: flex;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .column {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 28, 41);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>


  <div class="card">
    <label for="ticker">Ticker(s):</label>
    <input type="text" id="ticker" name="ticker" value="" style="text-transform:uppercase"><br>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column</h2>
      <p>INPUT INFO LATER INPUT INFO LATER</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column</h2>
      <p>INPUT INFO LATER</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column</h2>
      <p>INPUT INFO LATER</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily do that with a grid. Is easier for full repsonivness and youc an add as mcuh columns and boxes as you want. it will auto adjust.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Add a card effect for ticker(s) */

.card {
  background-color: rgb(24, 28, 41);
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(5, 105, 256);
  /*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 1%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: rgb(5, 105, 256)/*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style the topnav links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change color on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 1%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(5, 105, 256);
  /*rgb(196, 95, 0)*/
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 28, 41);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 1%;
  margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>


<div class="card">
        <label for="ticker">Ticker(s):</label>
        <input type="text" id="ticker" name="ticker" value="" style="text-transform:uppercase"><br>
</div>


<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>INPUT INFO LATER INPUT INFO LATER</p>
 </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>INPUT INFO LATER</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>INPUT INFO LATER</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```